# Buscador con ajax no busca

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un pequeño problema con el buscador que estoy haciendo. He buscado información por varios sitios e incluso visto videos para ver donde esta el fallo, pero no consigo verlo, ya que parece todo correcto. Dejo aquí el código a ver si alguien encuentra por que no busca. Aunque al menos muestra todo lo que hay en la base de datos.

Aquí empieza el `JS`:

```js
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(usuarios){
 $.ajax({
  url : '../consultarBusqueda.php',
  type : 'POST',
  dataType : 'html',
  data : {usuarios: usuarios},
 })

 .done(function(resultado){
  $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
 })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#buscar', function(){
 var valorBusqueda = $(this).val();
 if (valorBusqueda != ""){
  obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
 }else{
  obtener_registros();
 }
});
```

```html
<!--Aquí empieza el html:-->

<section>
  <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" class="form-control"   placeholder="Buscar...">
</section>
<br>   
<section id="tabla_resultado">
</section>
```

Aquí empieza el `php`:

```
<?
  session_start();

  include("conexion.php");

  if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
  }


  $tabla="";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY nombre";

  if(isset($_POST['usuarios'])){
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['usuarios']);
    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
  }

  $buscarUsuarios=$conn->query($sql);
  if ($buscarUsuarios->num_rows > 0)
  {
    $tabla.= 
    '<table class="table">
      <tr class="bg-warning">
        <td>NOMBRE</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
        <td>PASSWORD</td>
              <td>FECHA NACIMIENTO</td>
              <td>País</td>
      </tr>';

    while($fila = $buscarUsuarios->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $tabla.=
      '<tr>
        <td>'.utf8_encode($fila['nombre']).'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['email'].'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['password'].'</td>
              <td>'.$fila['fecha_nac'].'</td>
              <td>'.utf8_encode($fila['Pais']).'</td>
       </tr>
      ';
    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
  } else
    {
      $tabla="No se encontraron coincidencias.";
    }


  echo $tabla;
?>
```

Según yo lo que me tiene que fallar es algo del keyup, ya que lo único que hace es mostrar los datos generales, y no pasar nada por el con el `$_POST` y por eso no llega a pasar dentro del `if` y hacer la búsqueda.

Comment: ¿Has visto que muestra la consola del navegador?

Comment: No veo mucho sentido a la lógica. ¿Mandas a buscar al servidor cada vez que el usuario escribe un caracter? ¿Por qué no lanzar la búsqueda usando `onchange`? Aparte de eso, prueba a depurar tanto los datos que pasas en `data` como la variable `$sql` de PHP. La puedes devolver para verificar cómo se está construyendo. Es lo mínimo que deberías ya haber depurado en este caso.

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento, pestaña "Network", ¿la petición se genera? ¿retorna algo? ¿no se lanza?

Comment: La petición se lanza, data no recibe aparentemente valor y el $sql se escribe correctamente pero sin nada entre los % del like

Comment: Dentro del `if(isset($_POST['usuarios'])){`, haz un var_dump de `$_POST['usuarios']`, luego de `$q` y finalmente de `$conn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás declarando tu query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY nombre";
```

Y si viene el parámetro, no la redeclaras sino que la escribes con `echo`:

```
if(isset($_POST['usuarios'])){
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['usuarios']);
    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}
```

De manera que siempre ejecutas la primera, sin filtro.

**Bonus track**

Yo lo que veo es que tienes una **race condition**. Gatillas un llamado ajax en cada input, y si tecleas de corrido empiezan a encolarse N llamados.

Debieras hacer una especie de `debounce` para imponer una pausa entre llamadas.

```
var timeoutID=null;
$(document).on('keyup', '#buscar', function(){
  var valorBusqueda = $(this).val();
  clearTimeout(timeoutID); // Si hay un llamado en curso, lo cancelo

  timeoutID=setTimeout(function() { // agendo un nuevo llamado en 2s
    if (valorBusqueda != ""){
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }else{
        obtener_registros();
    }
  },2000);
});
```

(en rigor esto debiera hacerse cancelando el request... pero vamos por algo simple)

```js
function mockAjax(usuarios) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`<div>Se buscó <b>${usuarios}</b></div>`);
    }, 1500);
  });
}


function obtener_registros(usuarios) {
  usuarios = usuarios || 'Todos los usuarios';
  $("#proceso").text(`Ejecutando búsqueda: ${usuarios}`);
  mockAjax(usuarios)
    .then((result) => {
      $("#tabla_resultado").prepend(result);
      $("#proceso").empty();
    });
}
obtener_registros();
$(document).on('keyup', '#buscar', function() {
  var valorBusqueda = $(this).val();
  if (valorBusqueda != "") {
    obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
  } else {
    obtener_registros();
  }
});
var timeoutID = null;
$(document).on('keyup', '#buscar_debounced', function() {
  var valorBusqueda = $(this).val(),
      usuarios = valorBusqueda || 'Todos los usuarios';
  $("#proceso").text(`Se agenda búsqueda de: ${usuarios}`);
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    if (valorBusqueda != "") {
      obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    } else {
      obtener_registros();
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Búsqueda
<section>
<label for="buscar">Normal:
  <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..."></label>
  <label for="buscar">Con delay:
  <input type="text" name="buscar_debounced" id="buscar_debounced" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar con delay...">
  </label>
  <br>
  <small id="proceso"></small>
</section>
<br>
<section id="tabla_resultado">
</section>
```

Comment: Exactamente era eso, gracias por la ayuda, me ha servido mucho.